# Parsing JsonObject into ListView

Tags: android, json

```
 try{
            JSONArray name =new JSONArray();
            JSONObject data=json.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONObject orders=data.getJSONObject("orders");
            JSONObject country=orders.getJSONObject("US");
            Log.d("JSON",name.toString());
            Log.d("JSON",orders.toString());
            Log.d("JSON", country.toString());
            for(int i=0;i<country.length();i++){

                JSONObject c=country.getJSONObject(i);
                String title=c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String price=c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                String status=c.getString(TAG_PSTATUS);
      }
```

this line `JSONObject c=country.getJSONObject(i);` is giving me
    incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String

How do i fix this problem or maybe there is another way on doing this stuff
(i know the diference betwen Json obj and array )

JSON

```
US: {
19: {
orderId: "19"
uid: "US6625627"
remoteOrderNumber: null
orderPaymentStatus: "paid"
orderProcessingStatus: "new"
operatorComments: null
orderCancelReason: null
orderCancelDate: null
orderCancelAdmin: null
payed: "2014-09-17 16:03:03"
bought: null
delivery: null
transactionId: ""
paymentType: null
realPrice: "0.00"
isProblem: "0"
isMultiply: "0"
orderCanceledReasonName: null
itemId: "19"
itemBought: null
itemPaymentStatus: "paid"
itemProcessingStatus: "new"
itemCancelReason: null
itemPaymentType: null
itemTransactionId: null
itemRealPrice: "0.00"
shopTitle: "Ebay US"
}
```

Comment: At which row do you get the error? Can you add logcat-data?

Comment: Is TAG_PRICE an int?

Comment: oh sorry i called it error , let me fix it

Comment: i editet my post sorry for my mistakes, it's not an in , all string parsed from json obj , i know i should put get int but for testing purposes i put all ass string

Comment: Try the solution in my answer, if that's not working you might are parsing the JSON wrong? If so, you can ad the data you want to parse so I can explain how to parse it and provide sample code. @Alex

Answer (score 0):

The JSON-library wants a String as argument to getJSONObject(String) but you are passing a int, try doing this instead: `JSONObject c = country.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));`

Comment: it gives me a error in logcat 
org.json.JSONException: No value for 0

Comment: Please add a some sample json so I can check what's wrong @Alex

Comment: done , it's sample the wole code is a loot bigger,thank you a lott for helping

Comment: I'm afraid that the sample you just added is not JSON, try to copy it raw @Alex

Comment: I can do this for you, I will make a small snippet with how I think the JSON should be parsed. @Alex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61706/discussion-between-tim-lilleskutt-billstrom-and-alex).